# how to create a list from input argument in python3

Tags: python-3.x, list

I want to get an input from user and make a list from that input

I tried to use 'list' for create a list from input but it also make spaces into the list.
I can remove spaces but when i put 2 digit number it split it into two element of the list.
for example:

```py
L = list(input())
#6 9 10 
print(L)
#['6','','9','','1','0']
```

but I want to create a list like below :

`['6','9','10']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
_list = input("Enter data:").split()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
input_string = input()
L = input_string.split()
print(L)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation for your code.